# How can i match this text with a regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried to make a regex expression to match a piece of code, but no success.
The expression doesn't work in vs2008.

I've created this one:

```
/\*<parameters>\*/(?<value>[\r\n]*.*)/\*</parameters>\*/
```

the source to match is:

```
/*<parameters>*/ 
@parameter blue
,@parameter2 red
,@parameter3 green
,@parameter4 yellow /*</parameters>*/
```

Or better:

```
/*<parameters>*/  \r\n @parameter blue \r\n ,@parameter2 red \r\n ,@parameter3 green \r\n ,@parameter4 yellow /*</parameters>*/
```

Can anybody help me?

thanks,
Rodrigo Lobo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Regex out: `/\*<parameters>\*/(?<value>[^/]*)/\*</parameters>\*/`

A good tool for fooling around with real c# Regex patterns is regex-freetool on code.google.com

Answer (score 2):

`RegexOptions.Multiline` only changes the semantics of `^` and `$` -- you need `RegexOptions.Singleline` to let `.` match line-ends as well (a confusion I've been caught in myself;-).

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

```
/\*<parameters>\*/(.|\r|\n)*/\*</parameters>\*/
```

Alternatively, if you want to exclude the outer tokens from the match itself:

```
(?<=/\*<parameters>\*/)(.|\r|\n)*(?=/\*</parameters>\*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should match the all the text you specified, after you turn on the regex "Multiline" option.

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\*<parameters>\*/(?<value>[\r\n]*.*)/\*</parameters>\*/", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Match match = regex.Match(scriptText);
        return match.Success

it returns false..

Comment: "Singleline" is the option he needs, not Multiline. And the "[\r\n]*" part isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, you can use the Singleline modifier to let the dot match newline characters (\r and \n).  You can also use the inline form - `(?s)` - to specify it within the regex itself:

```
(?s)/*<parameters>*/(?<value>.*?)/*</parameters>*/
```

Also notice the reluctant quantifier: "`.*?`".  That's in case there's more than one potential match in the text; otherwise you would match from the first `<parameters>` tag to the last `</parameters>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to give you fish for this question, so you may want to try out this free tool (with registration) from Ultrapico called [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

I have stumbled with Regex for several time, and Expresso saved the day on all occassion.